# stop embedded video and go to next frame in flash

Tags: flash, flash-video

I have an embedded video(as movieclip) in flash from import video menu (not actionscript), then I want to move to next frame if a button is clicked.. when I cast

> gotoAndStop()
>   It goes to next frame for a second and then bounced and play the video again. How to make it go to the next frame and not going back again ?

Here is my button script :

```
stop();
enter_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, enter);
function enter(e){  
   gotoAndPlay(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gotoAndPlay(5);
```

Try to use a variable here, for example

```
int next = 0;
```

and then

```
gotoAndPlay(next+1);
```

In this case every time the function is called it will show next slide.